# What is the adj. describing something for those who don't know or have forgotten?

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to recall this one adjectives. It's often used to describe courses for people who need to return to the basics of Mathematics or English, for instance.

We might also assure a class that "using the writing center is not only for students who need __ help."

Comment: It sounds like "renumerative" but clearly is not.

Comment: Remedial, perhaps?

Comment: Courses geared towards people who need to return to the basics of a subject are often called **refresher courses**, or **refresher in fundamentals of <subject>**

Comment: @Mick, this is a factual information request and the correct answer has been provided. Why wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [***remedial***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remedial), but this would imply that the students understanding is defective or incomplete in some way. Note that *remedial* teaching is a lot different from taking a "refresher" course (or doing revision).

> **Remedial** *adjective* (EDUCATION)
>
> Mainly UK: relating to teaching that is intended to help people who have difficulties in reading or writing:
>
> - remedial classes/courses
> - She is a teacher of remedial English.

Cambridge Dictionary